# #include pcap.h make fails for hcxtools

Tags: kali-linux, make, pcap

I'm running the latest version of Kali on a VirtualBox, and I cannot get [hcxtools](https://github.com/ZerBea/hcxtools) installed. More specifically, I can not figure out how to get the dependency `pcap.h`. Running `make` in `/hcxtools` responds:

```
root@Lead-Pencil-Tip:~/hcxtools# make
cc -O3 -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu99  -MMD -MF .deps/wlanhcx2cap.d -o wlanhcx2cap wlanhcx2cap.c -lpcap 
wlanhcx2cap.c:12:10: fatal error: pcap.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pcap.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:81: wlanhcx2cap] Error 1
```

I've installed:

```
libssl-dev
libcurl4-gnutls-dev 
libcurl4-openssl-dev
libssl-dev 
zlib1g-dev 
libpcap-dev
```

The answers in issues [51](https://github.com/ZerBea/hcxtools/issues/51) and [61](https://github.com/ZerBea/hcxtools/issues/61) have not solved my problem.

Comment: What line are you speaking of?

Comment: No same error but with `<pcap/pcap.h>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install `libpcap0.8-dev`, which provides `/usr/include/pcap.h`.

In future, you can find this out by installing `apt-file` and using that:

```
apt-file search /pcap.h
```

(The first time you install it, you’ll need to run `sudo apt update`.)

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why that wasn't in the readme.

Comment: @MarkDeven: To me it seems also an error of ./configure . This should detect and give better warning about required dependencies